# Is it possible to customize the dates to pick in Acumatica Date Selector

Tags: acumatica

is it possible to disable some dates on the Acumatica Date Field Selector?

If yes, how?

My objective is I want to disable the data from dates behind before today's date.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What we have used is an attribute that controls the min value. So not changing the selector UI like your question but prevent any input using min and max values.  (remember the user can key in any value without using the selector)

Using this attribute on a date field you can control how many days before and/or after  today:

```
public sealed class DaysOffsetDateAttribute : PXDBDateAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Min date offset in days
    /// </summary>
    private int? _MinOffsetValue;
    /// <summary>
    /// Max date offset in days
    /// </summary>
    private int? _MaxOffsetValue;


    /// <summary>
    /// Minimum date offset in days. The offset adds days to the current business date to define the minimum date value.
    /// If no offset is defined then the default min date value is used without an offset
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <example>
    /// The example below shows a StartDate field that will not allow a date less that yesterday based on the current business date of today.
    /// 
    /// <code>
    /// [DaysOffsetDate(MinOffsetDays = "-1")]
    ///             public virtual DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    /// 
    /// </code>
    /// 
    /// </example>
    public string MinOffsetDays
    {
        get { return Convert.ToString(_MinOffsetValue); }
        set { _MinOffsetValue = ConvertToInt(value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maximum date offset in days. The offset adds days to the current business date to define the maximum date value.
    /// If no offset is defined then the default max date value is used without an offset
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <example>
    /// The example below shows a EndDate field that will not allow a date less that yesterday and greater than 30 days from now based on the current business date of today.
    /// 
    /// <code>
    /// [DaysOffsetDate(MinOffsetDays = "-1", MaxOffsetDays = "30")]
    ///             public virtual DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    /// 
    /// </code>
    /// 
    /// </example>
    public string MaxOffsetDays
    {
        get { return Convert.ToString(_MaxOffsetValue); }
        set { _MaxOffsetValue = ConvertToInt(value); }
    }

    private int? ConvertToInt(string stringValue)
    {
        int v;
        if (Int32.TryParse(stringValue, out v))
        {
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
        if (IsKey)
        {
            sender.Keys.Add(_FieldName);
        }

        DateTime businessDate = Common.Current.BusinessDate(sender.Graph);

        if (_MinValue == null)
        {
            if (_MinOffsetValue != null)
            {
                _MinValue = businessDate.AddDays(_MinOffsetValue.GetValueOrDefault());
            }
            else
            {
                _MinValue = Common.Dates.BeginOfTimeDate;
            }
        }
        if (_MaxValue == null)
        {
            if (_MaxOffsetValue != null)
            {
                _MaxValue = businessDate.AddDays(_MaxOffsetValue.GetValueOrDefault());
            }
            else
            {
                _MaxValue = Common.Dates.EndOfTimeDate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use it on a field as shown below. When zero min offset that indicates not less than today. We had a need to have so many days back so we used this attribute for either case. For example if you want a date no less than 7 days back use 7 as the value vs 0.

```
#region EffDate
public abstract class effDate : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected DateTime? _EffDate;
[DaysOffsetDate(MinOffsetDays = "0")]
[PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start Date")]
public virtual DateTime? EffDate
{
    get
    {
        return this._EffDate;
    }
    set
    {
        this._EffDate = value;
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Yeah, it is really possible for users to enter any date value, tho I have validations for that, my concern is for the presentation of the field, that the date values is greyed out or not pickable less than 7 days from today